# SharePoint Search hover panel display template customization

Tags: search

I have requirement to customize search results hover panel, where we need to add Delete link same as Edit,Follow,Send as shown in below image which delete the current item.

[image: Need To Add Delete link which delete the current item/selected item]

Comment: What have you tried and investigated till now? You will have to work with Display Templates for customizing hover panels.

Comment: I have added Version History and Edit Properties links to the hover panel and working fine . but i am not able to achieve delete link to delete the item.

Comment: I tried with deleteObject() function but it didn't worked. Can we use REST Api in Display templates?

Comment: Did you check this link? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn794232.aspx